# Update XML Node Data

Tags: c#

[image]

```xml
    <proceduralStep id="STEP_1">
        <para>
            This work package contains information required to remove grease 
            and oil from <acronym>
                <acronymTerm>GTE</acronymTerm>
                <acronymDefinition>Gas Turbine Engine </acronymDefinition>
            </acronym>/parts. There are two cleaning methods used, vapor-degreasing
            and steam cleaning. Steam cleaning is used when parts are too large
            for a solvent tank or for parts of materials that cannot be put into
            acid or alkaline tanks
        </para>
    </proceduralStep>
</proceduralStep>
```

I want update <para> node if I update text before `<acronymTerm>` then I should update ,If i want to update text after `</acronym>` in para node I should be update how we can update this part of data of para node in xml node
by using C#,means xml node contains data in two parts then we can update that xml node data by using c#

Comment: Is is XML or HTML?  You need to use a different library if HTML.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you use the `XDocument` class?

Comment: Sorry for the typo's in the, converted to text, xml stuff.  But text is easier to read than a picture...

Comment: Why are there two closing tags `</proceduralStep>`?

Comment: This code is from xml file I show only part of xml